# Can I use PHP to redirect to a file if a server is unreachable?

Tags: php, redirect

I host my own server at home but I use 000webhost as a means to take a domain and point it to my server with a PHP script (My ISP blocks port 80 for my "safety") I was wondering if I could take a PHP script and have it ping my web server and if it's down redirect to another website/file letting my few users know it's down. If PHP can't do this then what would you suggest?

Comment: I believe php can do this. All you may have to do, is just send http request to your server, and check the status. If the status is not OK, then maybe something is wrong. But, I'm just speculating, this.

Comment: Hm, I don't know for a fact if you can or cannot do this using PHP. However, from what I do know is that, you can setup more nameservers, so that if the first one can't be reached, it will fetch the next set of nameservers on the list of a given domain name, and/or the quickest one to respond, will be redirected to it. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
get_headers ( string $url [, int $format = 0 ] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Answer (score 0):

Use CURL if you want to ping the your site, then redirect.

```
function checkSite($url, $timeout = 80) {  
        $curl = curl_init($url);  
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);  
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);  
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  

        $data = curl_exec($curl);  
        $response = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
        curl_close($curl);  

    /**
     * Check if error ranges between 200 and 300
     */
    return ($response >= 200 && $response < 300) ? true : false;
}

//Check the site
if (checkSite("http://yourdomain.com")) {
    //YOUR REDIRECT HERE
}
```